# Can VIDEOWRITER_PROP_QUALITY do anything in OpenCV?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have a VideoWriter that I'm using to save videos. I am using `vid.set(cv2.VIDEOWRITER_PROP_QUALITY)` to try to adjust the quality of the final movie (I have adjusted from 10 to 100). According to [the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gga41c5cfa7859ae542b71b1d33bbd4d2b4a1cc2ab47f60a115ff9624ff71715b93b) it can be set between 0 and 100 "in some codecs." I have tried this for h264, divx, ffv1, and mjpg codecs. It seems to make no difference: the movies look the same and are the same size in memory. Are there any codecs for which I can actually change the bit rate for encoding my movies using `VIDEOWRITER_PROP_QUALITY`?

Comment: MotionJpegWriter seems to use it. For the others, ffmpeg bitrates are hardcoded, according to https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8961

Comment: @Micka do you know what that means, exactly? Would that be `MP4V` codec? I already tried `MJPG` and it didn't work. The problem is there are so many motion jpeg formats!

Comment: I dont know, sorry.

Comment: @eric, did you found any solution?

Comment: @VishakRaj no, but I also stopped trying.

Answer (score 0):

Setting VIDEOWRITER_PROP_QUALITY between [0,100] influences the image quality of  the JPEG encoded frames in MJPG video format. I guess the default quality is 75.