# OpenCV: Quality issue when reading, then writing with AVC1 codec

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, openh264

I tried using the VideoWriter for the first time and get this effect:

Read an AVC1/ yuv4:2:0 movie frame by frame with VideoCapture.
(Do nothing with the frames)
Write them out as AVC1/ yuv4:2:0 again.

No matter if and which value for VIDEOWRITER_PROP_QUALITY I set
the output size is about 6 times as big, and the quality is really bad.

When running the code it says:

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x31435641/'AVC1' is not supported with codec id 28 and form at 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x31637661/'avc1'

Failed to load OpenH264 library: openh264-1.7.0-win64.dll
    Please check environment and/or download library: https://github.com/cisco/openh264/releases

[libopenh264 @ 0000000002646aa0] Incorrect library version loaded
Could not open codec 'libopenh264': Unspecified error
```

I use openCV v.3.4.10.

When I provide openh264-1.7.0-win64.dll it says:

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x31435641/'AVC1' is not supported with codec id 28 and form at 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x31637661/'avc1'

    OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems, Inc.
```

and produces the strange AVC1 file mentioned above.

My code:

```
Mat frame;
string strFileName;

VideoCapture capt(strFileName); // YUV4:2:0
Size refS = Size((int) capt.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
                 (int) capt.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));

const size_t nNumberFrames (capt.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT));

VideoWriter VW ("Unchanged.mp4", CV_FOURCC('A','V','C','1'), capt.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS), refS); //  YUV4:2:0, extremly bad visual quality, also very big size

for (size_t i = 0; i < nNumberFrames; i++) {
    capt >> frame;
    VW.write (frame);
}

capt.release();
```

What is going on here?
What is the right code?

Comment: set videowriter quality property. if that doesn't suit you. request CAP_FFMPEG and set OPENCV_FFMPEG_WRITER_OPTIONS env var to request specific bitrate or quality/crf. -- "AVC1" is an invalid fourcc, use "avc1". error message says as much. -- browse the net for more info on these things, especially the env var. it's undocumented so far.

Comment: I did as you proposed: Changing the fourcc to "avc1" (and using openh264-1.7.0-win64.dll) goes without error message, but produces the same "strange" movie as before. cv::VIDEOWRITER_PROP_QUALITY doesn't do, as it's not intended for that (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61824667/can-videowriter-prop-quality-do-anything-in-opencv). Choosing CAP_FFMPEG does make no difference (I'm at Windows btw). Setting OPENCV_FFMPEG_WRITER_OPTIONS seems to be kind of "secret knowledge", anything but user friendly, and probably not working (e.g. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21155); only in dev!!

Comment: BTW crf23 is default for h264 in ffmpeg (https://superuser.com/questions/677576/what-is-crf-used-for-in-ffmpeg), and that result movie is about crf1 by file size and crf51 by "quality". Actually I really don't understand why the most simple use of a common task is messed like this... Strange... (???)

Comment: From assumption to knowledge. Setting OPENCV_FFMPEG_WRITER_OPTIONS to "crf;18|tune;grain"... produces... the same krank movie.

Comment: getting to look at your input and output data would help to assess... and *reproduce* the issue.

Comment: Nothing easier than that :)
https://c.gmx.net/@1155842887640945833/tGuyI73AQsSe6pnxDOCXmQ
E.g. have a look at the door frame - it "wobbles". And as said, see the file sizes.

Comment: yeah that quality loss is due to OpenH264. it's a very simple codec. the second file is merely "Constrained Baseline". it uses almost none of the features of H.264 that actually save bandwidth. I'm sure the codec itself doesn't even try very hard to compress, i.e. bitrate is wasted but at least it's compressing quickly. -- what's the goal of this? opencv is not for video compression. it's for computer vision. you might wanna investigate how to build opencv against a fully-featured ffmpeg, i.e. one with x264 codec. that'll do better. or check whether it can use the codecs of your GPU.

Comment: So... you can reproduce that result? And if yes: which version of OpenCV?